# VB.net changing an Excel Workbook name

Tags: vb.net

When I create a workbook, it is usually named "Book 1". I would like to change it to something like "My Workbook" without having to save the file. Is this possible? Here is the code I'm using to creat the book.

```
    Dim ExcelApplication As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
    Dim ExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Add
```

it would be nice if this worked:

```
    Dim ExcelWorkbook as Excel.Workbook = _
    ExcelApplication.Workbooks.Add(Name = "My Workbook")
```

or

```
ExcelWorkbook.Name = "My Workbook"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@joeB:this link can help you understand the problem with Microsoftinterop which does not have option to change workbook name with out saving it.
http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/602857-how-do-i-set-initial-excel-workbook-name